# Spotify iOS SDK Artist Name

Tags: ios, spotify

In the Spotify API on iOS, I do a call to get a `SPTPartialPlaylist`, which holds `SPTPartialTrack` objects, which hold a `SPTPartialArtist` object. However, this object doesn't hold the string name of the artist, it only holds their identifier, which looks like their unique identifier. How do I get the artist's name through the iOS API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the SPTTrack class.

```
SPTTrack.trackWithURI(player.currentTrackURI, session: session) { error, track in
    let trackName = track.name

    //Artist name
    guard let artist = track.artists.first as? SPTPartialArtist else {
       print("name missing?")
       return
    }

     let name = artist.name
})
```

[Googled link](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/407)

Comment: Thanks! That works. However, I could've just gotten it out of the `name` property from the `SPTPartialArtist` from the original call. The Spotify header files didn't mention that the name property would be filled, but it is.

Comment: LOL wow this documentation is a joke, thanks for finding that